# Having the tablet/smartphone camera in ThreeJS/WebGL background Cordova Conversion

Tags: android, cordova, camera, three.js, webgl

I develop a Web App' using ThreeJS and I convert it into an Android apk using Cordova.

Here is the thing, I would like to have the tablet or smartphone's camera preview in the background of my ThreeJS Scene. In order to complete this task, I'm using the [Camera Preview Plugin](https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreviewApp/tree/master/plugins/com.mbppower.camerapreview). However, when I use this plugin it can't be triggered by a load event. Moreover, when I finally activate this plugin with a button the camera isn't visible or the camera is hidding the ThreeJS Scene.

Does anyone have a solution to get the camera preview in the ThreeJS Scene's background ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that guys I have discover that in my app, I modify the body's background-color. So instead of getting the video behind the Three.Scene, I get nothing. Indeed, to get this Plugin working you need to have a transparent background color !